# how to use test-kitchen in multi node environment?

Tags: vagrant, docker, chef-infra, virtualbox, test-kitchen

test-kitchen [doesn't support](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/184) multi vm tasks, I tried to define a few nodes in Vagrantfile but it is too slow - start 5 virtual virtualbox VMs at once. Perhaps I need to use docker but the whole configuration becomes too complex, especially comparing usual test-kitchen setup.
What's the easiest way to test chef cookbooks with 4-5 separate linux nodes? For example: 2 rails apps, postgresql, solr, nginx.

Answer (score 0):

As you just said, kitchen doesn't support any kind of multi-node testing. Using something like CloudFormation or Heat is probably your best bet to quickly spin up whole test stacks, and then use Serverspec's remote mode to write tests.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Issue #184](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/184), Test Kitchen is not designed to do tests like that.
You might want to look into [Leibniz](https://github.com/Atalanta/leibniz). I haven't used it myself yet, but from what I understand, it might be what you're looking for.